# foreach results check

Tags: php, validation, function, foreach

my script let's people's post and short 15 address per time:

```
$err_msg = isValidFLR($flr_post, $ip);
    if (!$err_msg) {
    list($randlink, $lastid, $scr) = addLink($flr_post, $ip);
      $flr_post = check_input($flr_post);
      $url_array[$i]['number'] = $i + 1;
      $url_array[$i]['flr'] = $flr_post;
      $url_array[$i]['flr_substr'] = (strlen($flr_post) > 33) ? substr($flr_post, 0, 33) . '...' : $flr_post;
      $url_array[$i]['randlink'] = $randlink;
      $url_array[$i]['fullrand'] = $config['indexurl'] . $config['mod_rewrite_char'] . $randlink;
      $url_array[$i]['scr'] = $scr;
      $url_array[$i]['id'] = $lastid;
      $url_array[$i]['flr_length'] = strlen($flr_post);
      $url_array[$i++]['randlink_length'] = strlen($config['indexurl'] . $config['mod_rewrite_char'] . $randlink);
        } else {
        die('Error, omg');
         }
```

function isValidFLR check address hostname, preg_match (if it an url) and if it not in block list.

Problem is, that if user post like this(one address per line):

```
google.com
google.net
ksajdkljaskldjalsd.com
```

Script return's that all of the address wrong. If user try post only one, ALL good, valid address script works great.

So, problem with this script or URL validation check may be ?

What's your suggestion ?

EDIT:

```
function isValidFLR(&$flr_post,&$ip) {
preg_match_all("!://!",$flr_post,$matches);
  $match_count = count($matches[0]);
  if ($match_count>=2) {
    $flr_post = preg_replace("!(.+)://((.+)://(.+))!",'\2',$flr_post);
  }
  elseif ($match_count==0) $flr_post = 'http://'.$flr_post;
  if (!preg_match('!^(http|https|ftp)://[\w-]+\.[\w-]+(\S+)?$!i', $flr_post)) {
      //if (!preg_match('/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i', $flr)) {
    return 'wromg address: '.$flr_post;
  }
  else {
    $m = parse_url($flr_post);
    $hostname = strtolower($m['host']);
  }

  // is such host..
  if (preg_match('/^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/', $hostname)) {
    $ip = $hostname;
  } else {
    $ip = gethostbyname($hostname);
    if ($ip===$hostname) 
    return 'host not found: '.$flr_post;
  }

  // does host not blocked..
  if (in_array($ip,getIPs_array())) {
    return 'host blocked: '.$flr_post;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: If you don't include the script for function isValidFLR, how to tell?

Comment: Also, format your code nicely, white-spaces are not nice. Code snippet should be neat and relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split the input using ‘explode()‘, searching for "\n" then run the check on each of the lines.

Comment: Before url checking i do it (right after user press submit)
$flr_array = explode("\n", $flr_post);

Comment: Ahh, that seems, i have used explode in wrong place, thankfully, i haven't deleted my old version... for now everything works great. Thank you all who tryed help me.